# How to order SQL results with year and date?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have written PostgreSQL query which retrieves month,year and corresponding count. My query looks like:

```
SELECT 
(CASE
WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 01 THEN 'January'
WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 02 THEN 'February'
WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 03 THEN 'March'
WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 04 THEN 'April'
WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 05 THEN 'May'
WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 06 THEN 'June'
WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 07 THEN 'July'
WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 08 THEN 'Augst'
WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 09 THEN 'September'
WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 10 THEN 'October'
WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 11 THEN 'November'
WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 12 THEN 'December'
END) as MONTH ,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM app_pgm_req_dt) as YEAR,count(*) 
FROM app_pgm_choice GROUP BY MONTH,YEAR
order by YEAR
```

As results are ordered by month and year, its ordering month in alphabetical order and I want it to be ordered in actual month order.

Output:

```
"September";1968;4
"September";1970;1
"Augst";1971;3
"February";1975;1
"February";1977;1
"May";1977;1
"September";1978;1
"February";1978;3
"April";1978;1
"September";1979;1
.....
.....
```

for year...1978..results should be ordered like feb, april and sept
How can I do this?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but you can probably dispense with the CASE statement, by using an appropriate to_char function: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html. E.g. select to_char(now(),'month') at the moment (in April) will return "april"

Comment: Is the answer expected to work for MySQL as well? I'm not sure these tow products have the same date/time functionality?

Comment: Please check full example below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So simply order by month (`'01'`-`'12'`):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 01 THEN 'January'
         WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 02 THEN 'February'
         WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 03 THEN 'March'
         WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 04 THEN 'April'
         WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 05 THEN 'May'
         WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 06 THEN 'June'
         WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 07 THEN 'July'
         WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 08 THEN 'Augst'
         WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 09 THEN 'September'
         WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 10 THEN 'October'
         WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 11 THEN 'November'
         WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM app_pgm_req_dt) = 12 THEN 'December'
       END AS MONTH,
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM app_pgm_req_dt) AS YEAR,
       COUNT(*) 
  FROM app_pgm_choice 
 GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH, TO_CHAR (app_pgm_req_dt, 'MM')
 ORDER BY YEAR, TO_CHAR (app_pgm_req_dt, 'MM');
```

See [`TO_CHAR`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html) documentation. Check [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/28dc3/10).

Comment: Thanks @Trinimon. This is giving results as per my requirements :) Thanks Again :)